# Need to generate CSV file report out of ansible playbook output executed in check mode ( dry run)

Tags: python, shell, ansible

I am running a role to do the system hardening using ansible, which looks good, looking for generating a 'CSV' file with following fields- {IP_address, Task_Name, status( ok or changed) before enforcing the playbook.
Idea is to obtain a report before execution.

Below is sample output of the playbook:

```
TASK [system_hardening : Include OS Specific Variables] ************************
ok: [192.168.10.10]

TASK [system_hardening : Configure NTP - Install Package] **********************
ok: [192.168.10.10]

TASK [system_hardening : Disable chronyd services] *****************************
ok: [192.168.10.10]

TASK [system_hardening : Set some kernel parameters] ***************************
changed: [192.168.10.10] => (item={u'regexp': u'server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst', u'line': u'server google.com iburst'})
changed: [192.168.10.10] => (item={u'regexp': u'server 1.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst', u'line': u'server  google.com iburst'})
changed: [192.168.10.10] => (item={u'regexp': u'server 2.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst', u'line': u'server  google.com iburst'})
changed: [192.168.10.10] => (item={u'regexp': u'server 3.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst', u'line': u'server  google.com iburst'})

TASK [system_hardening : restart ntp services] *********************************

changed: [192.168.10.10]

TASK [system_hardening : Set Password Requirement Parameters Using pam_cracklib (Install)] ***
ok: [192.168.10.10]

TASK [system_hardening : Ensure password reuse is limited (/etc/pam.d/system-auth)] ***
changed: [192.168.10.10]

TASK [system_hardening : Ensure password reuse is limited (/etc/pam.d/password-auth)] ***
changed: [192.168.10.10]
```

Required CSV is

```
IP_Address,Task_Name, Status
192.168.10.10 ,SSH_Checks ,ok
192.168.10.11, SSH_Checks,changed
```

Any inputs please.

Comment: I don't know any concrete solutions right now, but have a look at the ansible callback plugins. These can be used to format the output of the ansible-playbook command differently. Either use one on the provided (There's a json output plugin available if you want to work with that ), or write your own:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html

Answer (score 1):

I saw that there is a [JSON callback for Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/json.html). It sets Ansible to display the output that would normally go the screen in JSON format. You could probably ingest that JSON data and easily convert it to CSV. Here's a post that shows [how to do the conversion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-json-to-csv-in-python/).

Here's the script from the post:

```
# Python program to convert 
# JSON file to CSV 


import json 
import csv 


# Opening JSON file and loading the data 
# into the variable data 
with open('data.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 

employee_data = data['emp_details'] 

# now we will open a file for writing 
data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'w') 

# create the csv writer object 
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file) 

# Counter variable used for writing 
# headers to the CSV file 
count = 0

for emp in employee_data: 
    if count == 0: 

        # Writing headers of CSV file 
        header = emp.keys() 
        csv_writer.writerow(header) 
        count += 1

    # Writing data of CSV file 
    csv_writer.writerow(emp.values()) 

data_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ansible-doc -t callback -l
```

lists available plugins to [manage stdout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#managing-stdout). If none fits there is an option to [write](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html) one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as of now if we can achieve it from a shell script, would be great. Will try plugins as well.